# Walking route distance between two locations using Rails Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, rails-geocoder

I am trying to get  Walking route distance between two locations using Rails Geocoder, but it taking the latitude and longitude values and giving the distance between them which doesn't suit in my application. I need to get the distance between two locations when I walk or travel in a car between the 2 points.

source: 733 River St, Boston, MA, 02136 ----> [42.264, -71.1028]

Destination: 830 Boylston Street, Chestnut Hill, MA, 02467 ---> ["42.3260327", "-71.14839090000001"]

Current Result: 4.878450592226187 miles(distance)

As per google maps the distance is 8.4 miles which I am expecting.

Comment: Simple distance between two points is not enough, as you have observed. You have to build a route between two points and calculate route's length. I haven't worked with geocoder gem, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there any ruby gem to get what I am expecting.

Comment: I don't know of such gems.

Comment: Thank you. Will post you if I get any solution.

Comment: Seems like you can get this information easily from the [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)